# How to reference a specific part of a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, rotten-tomatoes

Alright, so I am trying to create a simple thing that will tell me the showtimes of the movies at the theatre, the names of the movies, and the Rotten Tomatoes score in Python, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to get the meterScore.

```
actorCount = 0
actors = []
criticCount = 0
critics = []
franchiseCount = 0
franchises = []
movieCount = 3
movies = [{'name': 'Frozen II', 'year': 2019, 'url': '/m/frozen_ii', 'image': 'https://resizing.flixster.com/QZg2MuPQoRlWcWYAwufbQBlv-I0=/fit-in/80x80/v1.bTsxMzIwMzIxODtqOzE4Mjg3OzEyMDA7NTQwOzgxMA', 'meterClass': 'certified_fresh', 'meterScore': 76, 'castItems': [{'name': 'Kristen Bell', 'url': '/celebrity/kristin_bell'}, {'name': 'Idina Menzel', 'url': '/celebrity/idina_menzel'}, {'name': 'Josh Gad', 'url': '/celebrity/josh_gad'}], 'subline': 'Kristen Bell, Idina Menzel, Josh Gad, '}]
tvCount = 0
tvSeries = []
```

What I am trying to get from that list of data is the meterScore, if you scroll over to the right far enough you can see it. All this data is part of a bigger dictionary, which I named resultOne, but I don't think that matters. I just need some help figuring out how to reference and get the meterScore from the dictionary, so I can print it out, so when I want to see what movies and what rating they got I can just run this program and it will do it for me. I don't really use dictionaries that much, but the library I am using to get the Rotten Tomato data creates it as this very hard to reference dictionary, so any help is appreciated! What I don't get is that if I try to print(resultOne.movies) it says that that is not an attribute or something to that affect, even though when I put it into something that will print out the keys and values, such as I did to get the code above, it clearly shows it is a key. I also tried to print(resultOne.movies[meterScore]), but that didn't work either.

Comment: What is `resultOne` in `resultOne.movies[meterScore]` ?

Comment: It would help if you made a [mre], though maybe it's too late now since you've already got some answers.

Comment: movies is an array of dictionary so you need to get first element from movies[0]['meterScore']. Remember the quote around the dict key.

Comment: Are you just asking how to index into a dictionary?

Comment: Forgot to mention: variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Yes, I think I was asking how to index into a dictionary, but all the explanations I got really helped! Even though this question got downvoted I'm glad I got the help! (Before asking this I didn't even know what  indexing into a dictionary was, but now I do, so if this ever happens again I will be able to do it without help!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary values are looked up by their keys using `[]`, not `.`.

Now, the trick is that the `movies` key points to a list. So you need to mix two kinds of indexing that both use `[]`: dictionary indexing, which is by key, and list indexing, which is by position in the list (starting at `0`).

Ultimately, you want to do this:

```
score = resultOne['movies'][0]['meterScore']
                  ^         ^           ^    
                  |         |           |
     lookup in outer dict   |           |
                   first item in list   |
                                      lookup in inner dict
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 movies[0]['meterScore']
# 76
```

Answer (score 1):

In that snippet, `movies` is a list containing a dict. So index the list then index the dict:

```
movies[0]['meterScore']
```

If `movies` might contain more than one item (or zero for that matter), iterate over it instead to get a list of the `meterScore`s:

```
meter_scores = [movie['meterScore'] for movie in movies]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something like this to extract every meterScore from all the movies in the dictionary:

```py
listOfAllMeterScores = [ movie['meterScore'] for movie in movies ]
```